# I made a website using Yeoman/Grunt with Node.js just to build my application, how do I use the prerender or seo4ajax and index it?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, seo, prerender

I made a website using `Yeoman`; `grunt` ,  `generator-angular`,  `$routeParams` ... with `Node.js` just to **build** my application , how do I use the `prerender`or `seo4ajax` and index it?

Using Node.js as an application server could set like this: 
Run this on the command line:  `$ npm install prerender-node --save`

And when you set up your express app...:  `app.use(require('prerender-node'));`

**But, I use Node.js only to build my application, i do not have `express` this app,  how do I install and configure nginx (I use hosting Godaddy ) to get index the content of my site?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google provides some tools that make content indexing in ajax , now my site is appearing in search engine/research.

Go to: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch?hl=
Add a site , then go to **trace** > **Fetch as Google** and enter the pages you want to render and then index. There are many other excellent tools that site to assist us in indexing content in Ajax .

More info: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066467?hl=en

Yannick 's SEO4Ajax provided these modules to .htaccess and social networks functioned: Replace **yousite** with the name of your domain , replace **put you token** by his token (to get the token register at: seo4ajax.com ) then copy and paste in your .htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
RequestHeader set Host "api.seo4ajax.com"
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks
# Redirect yousite.com to www.yousite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yousite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.yousite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
# If requested with the _escaped_fragment_ query parameter, proxify
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(index.html) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_= [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=PROXIFY:true]

# If requested by a bot that does not support the specification, proxify
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(index.html) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  !(google.*bot|bing|msnbot|yandexbot|pinterest.*ios|mail\.ru) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  (bot|crawler|spider|archiver|pinterest|facebookexternalhit|flipboardproxy) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=PROXIFY:true]

# Proxification to SEO4Ajax
RequestHeader set Host "api.seo4ajax.com" env=PROXIFY
RewriteCond  %{ENV:PROXIFY}  true
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://api.seo4ajax.com/put you token/$1 [P,QSA,L]
</ifModule>
# html5 pushstate enable
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

Pass the information from your array for schemas and meta property .
Put that schemas and meta property in their views.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in grupo">
   <!-- Schemas -->
   <div span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"></span>
   <span itemprop="name" content="{{item.title}}"></span>

   <span itemprop="description" content="{{item.description}}"></span>

   <span itemprop="articleSection" content="Humor"></span>

   <span itemprop="image" content="http://www.yousite.com/images/{{item.img}}" ></span>
   </div>
   <!-- End - Schemas -->

   <!-- Meta property  -->
  <meta property="og:title" content="{{item.title}}" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.yousite.com/images/{{item.img}}" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="{{item.description}}" />
  <!-- End - Meta property  -->
</div>
```